# Connecting to metastore in hive after upgrade

Tags: hadoop, hive

I recently updated my Hive from v1.2 to v2.1.
Now every time I login it directly connects to the default hive metastore (metastore_db), instead of my thrift metastore port(https://localhost:9083)

Previously, every time I logged in, it showed something like this

> Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-1.2/lib/hive-common-1.2.0-mapr-1609.jar!/hive-log4j.properties

Now it shows something like this

> Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Hive2 will be not share a configuration with Hive1.x. You'll need to configure it again

In your Hive site XML

- `hive.metastore.uris` - this controls the first problem. It's recommended that you use Mysql or Postgres for an external metastore
- `hive.execution.engine` - You will need to install at least Tez. Spark on Hive is not feature complete, last time I checked. MapReduce has long been a poor default for quite some time

Comment: Is Spark on Hive good now?